# Split Python string into two on newline nearest the middle

Tags: python, string

I *have a string in python which is about 3900 character long*. T**he string has multiple chars including new lines a bunch of times**. For simplicity consider he following string:

```
s = "this is a looooooooooooooooooooooooooong string which is \n split into \n a lot of \n new lines \n and I need to split \n it into roughly \n two halves on the new line\n"
```

I would like to **split the above string into roughly two halves on \n** so expected result would be something like this :

```
first part = "this is a looooooooooooooooooooooooooong string which is \n split into \n a lot of "
second part = " new lines \n and I need to split \n it into roughly \n two halves on the new line\n"
```

I have this python code :

```
firstpart, secondpart = s[:len(s)/2], s[len(s)/2:]
```

but obviously this splits the string into exact half on whatever char happens to be at that position.

Comment: What is the problem with your solution? It looks fine to me.

Comment: @zvone he want to cut on a line break

Comment: huh, doesnt allow me to split it on \n . It just splits on whatever char is in the exact half. I literally mentioned that in my post.

Comment: Split on \n so that you get a list of fragments of text. Work out which item in the list occurs at about 50% of the total text, then re-join the two sublists on \n.

Comment: Then split it into lines first: `s.splitlines()`

Comment: @jarmod - its a random string, no items would occur 50 % of times. What logic to use to rejoin the strings then.

Comment: Or start at the midpoint and search backwards or forwards until you find the first '\n' and split on that?

Comment: @LewisFogden - sounds like a good solution, what would be the most pythonic way of doing it ?

Comment: I didn't say anything about the frequency of items in the list. You know the length of the original string. After you've split it on \n, you have a list of random length substrings. Start at the top of the list, sum the substring lengths (+1 per item to account for the \n if needed), and stop when you get to ~50%. Then re-join the two halves of the list on \n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`str.rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) and [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```py
s = "this is\na long string\nto be split into two halves"
mid = len(s)//2

break_at = min(
    s.rfind('\n', 0, mid),
    s.find('\n', mid),
    key=lambda i: abs(mid - i),  # pick closest to middle
)

if break_at > 0:
    firstpart = s[:break_at]
    secondpart = s[break_at:]
else:  # rfind() and find() return -1 if no '\n' found
    firstpart = s
    secondpart = ''

print(repr((firstpart, secondpart)))
# ('this is\na long string', '\nto be split into two halves')
```

`secondpart` will begin with the newline character.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mid = len(s)/2
about_mid = mid + s[mid:].index('\n')

parts = s[:about_mid], s[about_mid+1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way. Split the string on `'\n'`, and keep track of 3 things:

- The index in the split string list
- The absolute difference between the position of the current substring and the middle of the string
- The substring

For example:

```
s_split = [(i, abs(len(s)//2 - s.find(x)), x) for i, x in enumerate(s.split('\n'))]
#[(0, 81, 'this is a looooooooooooooooooooooooooong string which is '),
# (1, 23, ' split into '),
# (2, 10, ' a lot of '),
# (3, 1, ' new lines '),
# (4, 13, ' and I need to split '),
# (5, 35, ' it into roughly '),
# (6, 53, ' two halves on the new line'),
# (7, 81, '')]
```

Now you can sort this list by the second element in the tuple to find the substring closest to the middle. Use this index to build your strings by joining using `'\n'`:

```
idx_left = min(s_split, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
first = "\n".join([s_split[i][2] for i in range(idx_left)])
second = "\n".join([s_split[i][2] for i in range(idx_left, len(s_split))])

print("%r"%first)
print("%r"%second)
#'this is a looooooooooooooooooooooooooong string which is \n split into \n a lot of '
#' new lines \n and I need to split \n it into roughly \n two halves on the new line\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try this.

```
split=s.splitlines()
half=int(len(split)/2)

first=''.join(split[half:])
second=''.join(split[:half])
```