# How to return the first half of a string?

Tags: python, string

Assuming the string has at least one character in it. If the string length is odd, then you may assume it returns `(−1)/2` characters where `n` represents how many characters are in the original string.

For example:

```
'small' => 'sm'
```

I would also like to write another function that returns the 2nd half of a string.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all that we can help with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation). Together with [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) this will help you get the solution.

Comment: A few more relevant questions from this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789601/split-a-string-into-2-in-python ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311341/divide-a-string-into-two-halves-in-python ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62160102/splitting-strings-in-half-python ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934246/split-python-string-into-two-on-newline-nearest-the-middle

Answer (score 0):

You can just do an integer division (`//`) to get the integer value of the division to get the desired `(n-1)/2` value for odd `n`. Therefore, having the following:

```py
>>> my_string = "small"
>>> print(my_string[:len(my_string)//2])
sm
```

You could do the similar thing with using `math.floor` to be more explicit, but result is the same.